# Set a default variable in nginx with set

Tags: nginx

In nginx I can use `set` to define a variable, but is it possible to define a default?

e.g.

```
set $foo bar if $foo is not defined
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
map $foo $new_foo {
    default  $foo;
    ''       bar;
}
```

or

```
if ($foo = '') {
    set $foo bar;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/map
- http://nginx.org/r/if

Comment: Using the if method I got `using uninitialized "foo" variable` warning in my log. Can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
map $foo $foo {
    default '';
}
map $foo $bar {
    default '';
    'bar' 'bar';
    'foo' $foo;   <----- nginx: [emerg] unknown "foo" variable
}
```

`map $foo $foo {}` solves error `nginx: [emerg] unknown "foo" variable`
  - just doesn't look right - but it works.

Note: `map` must be in block `http {}` (`nginx/conf.d`)

Answer (score 0):

`map $foo $foo {}` gives me `cycle while evaluating variable "foo"` error message in the nginx error log.

Now,

```
map $foo $foo_with_default {
  default 'bar';
  ~. $foo;
}
```

does work and it's also semantically correct: if the regular expression matches anything then the result will be `$foo` if it doesn't then there are no characters to match so it becomes `bar`. I do not think the configuration syntax for nginx makes it possible to distinguish between an empty string and an undefined variable. I believe you need openresty and a nil check for that.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current Nginx versions in 2023 (v1.20+), the above approaches do not seem to work and all create either a warning or failure to start up in my usage when adding these into `nginx.conf`.

In my case I needed to overwrite the Host header, conditionally, in an included general configuration file shared by many sites, whilst only setting that for the sites that needed it.

In this case, in your `http` block (e.g. `nginx.conf`):

```
map '' $proxied_host {
  default '';
}

map "$proxied_host" $resolved_host {
  default $host;
  ~. $proxied_host;
}
```

and in the included configuration file in every location:

```
proxy_set_header            Host $resolved_host:$server_port;
```

then in the sites that need to overwrite it, in the location block:

```
set $proxied_host your.example.com;
```

This is the only way I found to avoid:

1. Floods of warnings in error.log saying `using uninitialized "proxied_host" variable`
2. Errors related to using uninitialized variables in the map like `nginx: [emerg] unknown "proxied_host" variable`
3. Errors relating to cycles in variables `cycle while evaluating variable "proxied_host"`