# How to parse and retrieve both subdomain and host name label in Nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I'm working with an environment for testing purposes based on a few magento versions over a nginx + php-fpm + mysql stack, i puts each distribution in a different folders and in the nginx vhost config file i'm using the following 
sentence:

```
server_name ~^(?<version>.+)\.magento\.test$;
root [root_path]/distro/$version;
```

So until here i can get any dinamic url mapped to its folder

```
ce107.magento.test => [root_path]/distro/ce107/
ce108.magento.test => [root_path]/distro/ce108/
ce109.magento.test => [root_path]/distro/ce109/
```

The problem starts when i try to use the "host name label" to switch websites on each distribution:

```
us.ce107.magento.test, ar.ce107.magento.test ...
```

because nginx looks for: **[root_path]/distro/us.ce107/** and **[root_path]/distro/ar.ce107/** folders.

So i need to parse and retrieve the values of:

```
 [ws_code].[version].magento.test
```

and i can't figure out how to do it, maybe i could use "map $host $ws_code {}" to parse $ws_code value, and apply some regex to remove "ws_code." part from the $version

BTW obviously i can do it "harcoded" but i want to keep it "dinamic"

Can someone give a hand with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please specify, where `[ws_code].[version].magento.test` should point by example? Also do you need both 3rd and 4th level domain support (i.e. both with and without `[ws_code]`) or just 4th devel domain support?

Comment: Ok @jollyroger i forgot to explain this part... based on previous example, both  `us.ce107.magento.test` and `ar.ce107.magento.test` must point to same folder `([root_path]/distro/ce107)` so the 4th level is just used as a var for send it to php ( _fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $ws_code;_ ) - Very good point about 3rd and 4th level support, in some case maybe i'll need it eg:  `us.ce107.magento.test`  and `ce107.magento.test` support, but this is just an "extra" because i can force it to use always a 4th level url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<version>.+)` regexp will use greedy match and assign it to `$version` variable. You could do just the same to match both `ws_code` and `version`:

```
server_name ~^(?<ws_code>.+)\.(?<version>.+?)\.magento\.test$;
root [root_path]/distro/$version/$ws_code;
```

I've used greedy match for `[ws_code]` and non-greedy for `[version]`. Also I'd use something more deterministic like `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` to exclude domain separator dot sign from possible match like this (in this case we don't need to check wether match algorithm is greedy or not):

```
server_name ~^((?<ws_code>[a-z]+)\.)?(?<version>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.magento\.test$;
root [root_path]/distro/$version;
```

Additional `()?`braces over ws_code matchig will allow this configuration to match both 3rd level domain with just one variable available and 4th level domain with two variables available. You might want to [assign a default variable](https://serverfault.com/a/453147/52873) for `ws_code`.

Comment: Thanks @jollyroger !!! it works perfect PS: i'll never understan Regex :(